# If you have external tasks that gather information about a model should it live in the model as a method?

Tags: django, django-models

For example we have a method that fetches additional information about a model from third party APIs. Is it okay to put this as a method on the model or should it live outside?

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = ...
    location = ...


    def fetch_location(self):
        # fetch the location from another server and store it.
        self.location = "result"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is related to the instance than it can be the right place to put it. Only if you get a lot of these you might want to wrap them in a different class for your own readability (i.e. knowing what is internal and what is external from the instance perspective).

The way I generally do it:

- Manager: anything pertaining a group of Model instances
- Model: anything pertaining a single Model Instance

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you think in terms of Object Oriented Programming, the answer is "yes":

If "the object can do something", than it should be included as a member function (aka method).

But: If several different classes would need the same functionality (e.g. an "Entity Owner" would like to fetch the location by himself without calling my_entity.fetch_location), you should consider a (abstract) class above both classes which implements the behaviour.

If you have to call the method without an existing instance (which seems not to be the case in your example), you might consider writing the method outside of a class or you add the  `@staticmethod` decorator which allows you to call `Entity.fetch_location` (remember to omit *self* in this case since there is no *self* if there is no instance.) I would prefer the staticmethod over a global method because the caller will always know, which class it relates to.

```
@staticmethod
def fetch_location():
    # fetch the location from another server and store it.
    self.location = "result"
```